# Query a pandas df grouped by one feature, multiple conditions and outputting it into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas df (dummy df, the original one consists of 100'000s of entries).

```
columns = ['id', 'answer', 'is_correct']
data = [['1','hello','1.0'],
       ['1','hello', '1.0'],
       ['1','bye', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'cat', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Milan', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Milan', '1.0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
df

   id   answer  is_correct
0   1   hello   1.0
1   1   hello   1.0
2   1   bye     0.0
3   2   dog     0.0
4   2   cat     1.0
5   2   dog     0.0
6   3   Milan   1.0
7   3   Paris   0.0
8   3   Paris   0.0
9   3   Milan   1.0
```

The goal is to create a list of lists based on conditions.

**Conditions**:
For every *unique* `id` I would like to have a correct `answer` (`is_correct == 1.0`), then a (pseudo) randomly picked `answer` within that `id` and finally the `is_correct` value (1.0 or 0.0) for the randomly `answer`.

```
[['hello', 'bye', 0.0], ['cat', 'dog', 0.0], ['Milan', 'Milan', 1.0], ...]]
```

I only need two answers from every *unique* `id`. All ids consist of more than 2 answers. There are no NaNs in any of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def filt(grp):
    is_correct = grp['is_correct']=='1.0'
    if is_correct.any():
        sample = grp.sample()
        return [grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[0],
                sample['answer'].to_list()[0],
                sample['is_correct'].to_list()[0]]

print(df.groupby('id').apply(filt).to_list())  # --> [['hello', 'bye', '0.0'], ['dog', 'dog', '0.0'], ['Milan', 'Milan', '1.0']]
```

update - `.apply(bool)` was replaced with `==1.0` to handle the `'1.0'` and `'0.0'` strings

Comment: Cool, works on the dummy df! Interestingly, if I do not add the index to the dummy df manually, the code provided won't work because the automatically generated index starts with 0 I assume. Then, if I do df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1) the index starts with 1 but it still does not work. Any idea why that is the case?
I edited the question according to that.

Comment: need to add iloc[0] in the first return element. I updated the answer

Comment: The second list inside the list of lists says ['dog', 'dog', '0.0'], but for any 'dog', the is_correct value is never = 1.0

So is that correct?

Comment: Nice catch, @amit. The 0.0 is a string and bool('0.0') is True. Fixed with `=='1.0'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
>>> import random

>>> keep = []

>>> for val in df.id.unique():
>>>     temp_keep = []
>>>     temp_df_correct = df[(df.id==val) & (df.is_correct=='1.0')]
>>>     temp_df_notcorrect = df[(df.id==val) & (df.is_correct=='0.0')]

>>>     correct_index = random.choice(temp_df_correct.index)
>>>     temp_keep.append(temp_df_correct.loc[correct_index,'answer'])
>>>     temp_df_correct.drop(correct_index, inplace=True)
    
>>>     new_df = temp_df_correct.append(temp_df_notcorrect, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
>>>     temp_keep.extend(random.choice(new_df[['answer', 'is_correct']].values))
>>>     keep.append(temp_keep)

>>> print(keep)

    [['hello', 'bye', '0.0'], ['cat', 'dog', '0.0'], ['Milan', 'Milan', '1.0']]
```

Comment: Great, works on the dummy df! On my df I am getting an `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence` error. However, I double checked and I do not have any NaNs in the df. Any idea what the origin could be?

Comment: I think I found the issue, my dummy df starts with the index 0 but my original df with 1.

Comment: Interestingly, if I do not add the index to the dummy df manually, the code provided won't work because it starts with 0. Then, if I do df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1) the index starts with 1 but it still does not work. Any idea why that is the case?
I edited the question according to that.

Comment: Well, my friend the only time it won't work and the reason you are getting this error is that I had assumed that there will always be a correct answer for a given id.

So in your real data, there is a possibility that for a certain id, all the values under is_correct are 0.0

Now the answer that Lior has written, is wrong in that case. Look at the answer he has provided. The second list inside the list of the list is- ['dog', 'dog', '0.0']. Is dog ever correct? No right? If that's what you want- an incorrect value if none is correct? I can force it to do that if you want.

Your call.

Comment: That error is bound to occur given there is no is_correct = 1.0 for a certain id in your original data.

If you want, you can get a string as "NONE CORRECT" printed back if none is correct.

Comment: I see, should have noted / included that in the dummy df. I believe Lior now adjusted his answer based on your comment, so that will do for me. I would upvote your comments and answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It's okay Exa, I am just happy to know your issue is resolved. Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on pandas, but I have used it quite a lot lately. You can group your dataframe with the following code:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(["id"])[["answer", "is_correct"]].agg(list)
```

After that, each row will group by id:

```
                          answer            is_correct
id                                                    
1            [hello, hello, bye]       [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
2                [dog, cat, dog]       [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
3   [Milan, Paris, Paris, Milan]  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

I think that you can part from this  and the rest of logic of your question is easier to implement. You can iterate through rows of the resulting dataframe grouped_df with the following loop:

```
for row in grouped_df.iterrows():
    print(row[1]["answer"])
    print(row[1]["is_correct"])
```

Hope it helps. Maybe there is a more vectorized way of doing this, but as I said before, I am not an expert.